# How to block people that aren't your friends?

Tags: miitomo

I've got a person in Miitomo that is pretty annoying. I want to block her, but I have no idea how. I tried:

- blocking her from the comments section, but holding the comment only shows a report button, not a block button.
- blocking her from the friends list of a friend, but it only shows a button to send a friend request.

She unfortunately isn't showing up in my suggested friends, where blocking is actually possible without adding her as friend.

**How do I block someone on Miitomo if he/she is not in my friends list and not in my suggested friends?**

Comment: When you say "block" in reference to a user who is not your friend, are you referring to an action that would hide their comments? Prevent them from showing up in your suggested friends? Or something else? Just want to make sure I understand exactly what you mean.

Comment: You can currently block friends that are in your friendslist. This unfriends them and hides their messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Miitomo 1.2, it is possible to block people from the comments section and the heart lists:

> Friend requests and blocking can now be done within comment and heart
>   lists.

[Source](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nintendo.zaaa&hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

There is **no way** (currently) to block, and or ignore people that aren't your friend, just as there is no way to hide/block friends of friends.

Because To block someone on Miitomo, you must first be friends with that person (suggested friends as well). From there you can unfriend or block other Miitomo users. But you could add the person(s) you want to block then do so. In order to do this, select "Friends" from your Mii's character room. Touch the "i" icon next to the friend you want to remove, and then select either "Block" or "Unfriend".

Since Miitomo is a social networking app, the whole point is to collect as many friends as possible, and learn stuff about them, so an acceptance of your request (so you can block them) is likely.

However, if someone is spamming, harassing, or otherwise committing any other violation of the rules, the report button could be used.

Comment: Sorry, but future updates may fix this problem.